# java how to escape unrecognized character on hexadecimal conversion

Tags: java, wireshark

Data from WireShark:

[image: data from WireShark]

the data is

```
0000   01 01 00 b6 00 00 01 00 16 00 00 00 12 00 00 00
0010   02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 53 00
0020   45 00 4c 00 45 00 43 00 54 00 20 00 2a 00 0d 00
0030   0a 00 20 00 20 00 46 00 52 00 4f 00 4d 00 20 00
0040   5b 00 56 00 69 00 73 00 61 00 4f 00 72 00 64 00
0050   65 00 72 00 44 00 42 00 5d 00 2e 00 5b 00 64 00
0060   62 00 6f 00 5d 00 2e 00 5b 00 4c 00 65 00 61 00
0070   64 00 43 00 6f 00 75 00 72 00 73 00 65 00 5d 00
0080   0d 00 0a 00 20 00 20 00 77 00 68 00 65 00 72 00
0090   65 00 20 00 43 00 6f 00 75 00 72 00 73 00 65 00
00a0   3d 00 20 00 27 00 cf 6b 63 5b a6 5e 27 6b 32 6d
00b0   fe 8b 0b 7a 27 00
```

After transfered it should be like as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [VisaOrderDB].[dbo].[LeadCourse]
  where Course= '每季度欧洲课程'
```

my java code is as following:

```
public static String hexString2String(String src) {  
    String temp = "";  
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length() / 2; i++) {  
        temp = temp  
                + (char) Integer.valueOf(src.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2),  
                        16).byteValue();  
    }  
    return temp;  
}  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    System.out.println(hexString2String("010100b60000010016000000120000000200000000000000000001000000530045004c0045004300540020002a000d000a0020002000460052004f004d0020005b0056006900730061004f007200640065007200440042005d002e005b00640062006f005d002e005b004c0065006100640043006f0075007200730065005d000d000a002000200077006800650072006500200043006f0075007200730065003d0020002700cf6b635ba65e276b326dfe8b0b7a2700"));  
}
```

the result is like:

[image: java result picture]

so anyone know how to work it out?

Comment: Most likely an issue with different encoding: when converting a byte stream to a stream you must define which byte(s) map to which characters, otherwise you will end up with gibberish.

Comment: usually as String.getBytes ("UTF-8");

Comment: It's an encoding that uses at least 2 bytes per character. Treating it as UTF-16LE (little endian) gets the correct result, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not ASCII (nor UTF8): it's UTF16 (you can see that it encodes a single character in 2 bytes). Also, you're capturing the packet, so you need to strip the package header off first - that's not the text you're looking for.

To decode the UTF-16 data (I used your code as a starting point):

```
public static String hexString2String(String src) {
    byte[] data = new byte[src.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length() / 2; i++) {
        data[i] = Integer.valueOf(src.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16).byteValue();
    }
    return new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary:

```
String s =  "010100b6000001001600000012000000" +
            "02000000000000000000010000005300" +
            "45004c0045004300540020002a000d00" +
            "0a0020002000460052004f004d002000" +
            "5b0056006900730061004f0072006400" +
            "65007200440042005d002e005b006400" +
            "62006f005d002e005b004c0065006100" +
            "640043006f0075007200730065005d00" +
            "0d000a002000200077006800650072006" +
            "500200043006f0075007200730065003d" +
            "0020002700cf6b635ba65e276b326dfe8b" +
            "0b7a2700";
String result = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
System.out.print(result);
```